# Transform: perspective теряется при анимации

Tags: javascript, css

Есть 3д куб. У него стоит transform perspective 900px. При первой анимации сразу теряется это свойство. Почему?

Вот песочница на пример http://jsbin.com/genexe/3/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Потому что свойству transform Вы присваиваете новое значение, и старое заменяется новым. А в новом нет perspective.